# Can't set different json values with different values

Tags: bash, jq

Linux Mint 20.2

Here **report.empty.json**

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "project": "",
  "Severity": [],
  "issues": []
}
```

I want to set value = 500 (int value) to "total" and "MY_PROJECT".

To do this I use tool "jq"

Here by bash script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PROJECT_KEY=MY_PROJECT
readonly PAGE_SIZE=500

jq --arg totalArg "$PAGE_SIZE" '.total = $totalArg' report.empty.json > report.json
jq --arg projectKey "${PROJECT_KEY}" '.project = $projectKey' report.empty.json > report.json

echo "Done"
```

But it set only key **project**. The key **total** is not changed.
Content of file **report.json**

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "project": "MY_PROJECT",
  "Severity": [],
  "issues": []
}
```

But I need to update **BOTH KEYS**.

The result must be:

```
{
  "total": 500,
  "project": "MY_PROJECT",
  "Severity": [],
  "issues": []
}
```

Comment: `jq ... input | jq ... > output` ?

Comment: This isn't really a jq-specific problem in any meaningful way. `progA <in >out; progB <in >out` only applies `progB` to `out`, because the second program overwrites the output from the first one without ever reading it.

Comment: BTW -- POSIX specifies that all-caps variable names are reserved for variables meaningful to the shell and operating system. (Well -- more strictly, it specifies that only names that _aren't_ all-caps are reserved such that POSIX-defined tools shouldn't rely on them or change behavior based on them; but the effect is the same). The word of the spec refers to environment variables, but setting _any_ shell variable with the same name as a preexisting environment variable will overwrite the latter, so the rules necessarily apply to all shell variables.

Comment: See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph; following that convention saves a lot of trouble (`for PATH in */; do ...` is a mistake we see a lot of here; `for path in */; do ...` is a lot safer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second command reads from `report.empty.json` instead of the already-modified `report.json`.

You could chain the `jq`

```sh
jq --arg totalArg "$PAGE_SIZE" '.total = $totalArg' report.empty.json |
jq --arg projectKey "${PROJECT_KEY}" '.project = $projectKey' >report.json
```

But a better solution is to use just use one command.

```sh
jq --arg totalArg "$PAGE_SIZE" --arg projectKey "$PROJECT_KEY" '
   .total = $totalArg | .project = $projectKey
' report.empty.json >report.json
```

Comment: Then for arrays like `issues`, things seem more complicated. What's your opinion on [my proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69916942/1765658)?

Comment: @jkegami Is it possible "jq" to set values not from report.empty.json file, but from bash variable?

Comment: In bash, yes. Use `<<<"$VAR"` to redirect STDIN so it reads from a virtual file which has the value of `$VAR` for content. There's also `<( printf %s "$VAR" )`, which produces a file name for a virtual file with the same content. [Demo](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/02ed4f65c5a4f2131f4763fb9d1f83b4)

Answer (score 1):

#### My proposal for *How to populate JSON values, using `jq`*

Thinking about **How to process *arrays* using jq**, here is my modified version of your script. (Of course, you could keep `empty.json` out of script)...

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r  projectKey=MY_PROJECT
declare -ir pageSize=500

declare -a issueList=()
declare -i issueCnt=0
declare issueStr='' jqCmd='.project = $projArg | .total = $totArg | .issues=[ '
declare promptMessage='Enter issue (or [return] if none): '
while read -rp "$promptMessage" issue && [ "$issue" ];do
    promptMessage='Enter next issue (or [return] if no more): '
    issueCnt+=1
    issueList+=(--arg is$issueCnt "$issue")
    issueStr+="\$is$issueCnt, "
done
jqCmd+="${issueStr%, } ]"

jq --arg totArg "$pageSize" --arg projArg "$projectKey" \
   "${issueList[@]}" "( $jqCmd )" <<-EoEmptyJson
{
    "total": 0,
    "project": "",
    "Severity": [],
    "issues": []
}
EoEmptyJson
```

Sample run (I want to add two issues):

```
./reportJson
Enter issue (or [return] if none): Foo
Enter next issue (or [return] if no more): Bar Baz
Enter next issue (or [return] if no more): 
{
  "total": "500",
  "project": "MY_PROJECT",
  "Severity": [],
  "issues": [
    "Foo",
    "Bar Baz"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No answer (so far) accounts for the requirement that `total` be of type `int`. This can be accomplished by using `--argjson` instead of `--arg`. Here's my two cents:

```sh
jq --argjson total 500 --arg project "MY_PROJECT" '. + {$total, $project}' report.json
```

```json
{
  "total": 500,
  "project": "MY_PROJECT",
  "Severity": [],
  "issues": []
}
```

Comment: But what about key "Severity"? It's array. Can I use "jq --argjson" for it?

Comment: Field `.Severity` is an array inside the JSON object. You never defined it outside `jq` (as opposed to `PROJECT_KEY` and `PAGE_SIZE`). If outside it is a Bash array, you cannot simply use `--arg` as it works with strings only. However, you could (with a separate `jq` call) convert it into a JSON array, which for Bash *is* a string, and then feed it into the actual `jq` call using `--arg` and de-serialize it inside using the `fromjson` builtin.